# Selenium Grid and Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have all my jenkins environment under a pipeline structure with multibranch pipelines.

I am starting to integrate it with broswer testing using selenium grid. What do you think is the best way to integrate selenium under a pipeline  with a Jenkinsfile?.

Thanks you by the help!